# Yahoo Pipes - Return items in a feed by range?

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

There exists an RSS feed with over 1000 items.  I want to create a Yahoo Pipes RSS feed that returns a subset of the feed's items, specified by the index of the first and last item.  For example, I could pass in first=500 and last=600, and the Pipe will return an RSS feed with only the 500th through 600th itemd in the source feed.  Is this possible with Yahoo Pipes, and if so can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out so rapidly, the best way to work with Yahoo pipes is to think much like you would when making up a Unix pipeline -- here, the obvious Unix pipeline would be to take the tail of the head, and the Yahoo pipes approach is perfectly analogous (except that by calling 'head' by the name of 'truncate' they're putting a little obstacle in your way;-).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out... use the truncate filter followed by the tail filter with inputs a and b respectively.  This results in [a-b:a] items.